# very weird output using laravel 5.4 Undefined property: stdClass::$Amount

Tags: php, laravel, stdclass

1.

```
dd($rate['SCINS']);
```

Got this:

```
{#494 ▼
  +"Amount": "3.96"
  +"AddOnType": "SC-A-INS"
  +"ProhibitedWithAnyOf": {#495 ▶}
}
```

2.

```
$amount = $rate['Amount'] + $rate['SCINS']->Amount;
```

Got this:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$Amount

3.

```
$amount = $rate['Amount'] + $rate['SCINS']->Amount;
dd($amount);
```

Got This:

```
10.26
```

Can anyone explain why this happen?
How can I get the sum of `$rate['Amount'] + $rate['SCINS']->Amount` ?

Comment: Have you tried $rate->Amount? If not once try and let me know

Comment: dd($rate->Amount);Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try like this $rate['SCINS']->Amount

Comment: dd($rate['SCINS']->Amount);Got "3.96". Its looks find. but when i use $amount = $rate['Amount'] + $rate['SCINS']->Amount; I got Undefined property: stdClass::$Amount

Comment: Do you use $rate['SCINS']->Amount in a loop? If yes, you need to check every time, is $rate['Amount'] not empty.
Edited : Or, try get the value $rate['SCINS']['Amount']

Comment: It seems like the `Amount` property isn't always present on the `$rate` object. Otherwise I can't see the difference between 2. and 3.

Comment: Vahe Shak, you are right, it's inside a foreach. It's explained everything. so dd returned a correct value for the first iteration. and "Undefined property" was for some later iteration. Thank you so much!